# Where are Cygwin installer settings stored?

Tags: cygwin

I want to install cygwin on a target computer.
I want to delete the Cygwin installer settings so my installer only uses default values.

I deleted C:\cygwin and the package folder but the installer still starts up using settings from old installations.

Where does the Cygwin installer store its settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only setting that Cygwin setup is storing on the Register is
the location of the various installations at

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Cygwin\Installations
```

Usually the defaults are

```
C:\cygwin       (for the 32 bit version)
C:\cygwin64     (for the 64 bit version)
```

You can tell anyway Setup to use a different directory or disk,
setting a different `Root directory`.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I have to add that the same key exists under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE